# jQuery: Delay of fadeIn, slideDown or something similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, wait

Last night I was wondering how it is possible to delay a fadeIn or something similar. It's not something I'm working on, I was just wondering.

If you have a list, with links that activates a tooltip on hover, for example. How do you make it "wait" until you have hovered for 1 second?

I want to do this, so the tool tips doesn't "flicker" when you hover along the list. If you understand what I mean.

The same thing could be used at logins. If you see http://twitter.com/ (not logged in). If the login box in the top, was activated with hover, and not click, it would disappear again if your cursor left the login box. Is it possible to set a "delay" so your cursor could leave the login box, and come back, without it disappearing...?

**In short:**

- How do you activate a script, when hover after x seconds?
- How do you set a delay for hiding a div (when not hovering) that was activated by hover?
- Is it the same thing, just in reverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a quite advanced hover plugin that waits for your mouse to **slow down** before triggering arbitrary code - http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Alternatively, if you don't need something so advanced... you can simply trigger the animation in a `setTimeout()`, and on mouseleave call `clearTimeout()`

Yet another alternative, is to not bother with the delay. If you do a `.stop().fadeIn()` and a `.stop().fadeOut()` rather than a simple `show()` and `hide()`, you won't get a "flicker" and the effect will look quite nice.

(You can look at `.delay()` for delaying animation-related code - although this will only delay the animation, even if you move off the div before the delay finishes.)